# Username/Password browser autofill not working

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have the following username-password form in a angular project which uses angular-material. What I want is the browser (using Google Chrome for testing), suggesting me the list of usernames I already have logged in with for different other sites. Even with `autocomplete` attributes set up in input fields I still cannot get browser suggesting me saved usernames. Any help on this is appreciated.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" autocomplete="on">
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="credential.username" name="username" id="username" #username="ngModel" pattern='\S+_\d{6}' autocomplete="username">
      <mat-error *ngIf="username.invalid && (username.dirty || username.touched) && (username.errors?.pattern)">
        Please enter a valid username
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
      <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="credential.password" name="password" id="password" #password= "ngModel" autocomplete="current-password">
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-card-content>
  <button type="submit" mat-stroked-button color="accent" [disabled]="username.invalid || password.invalid">Log in</button>
</form>
```

**P.S.**

In developer tools in chrome I found that the `autocomplete` attribute getting value 'off' automatically for username input field, just as I click on username input field to type something. But not for the password.

*After first reload before typing*
[image]

*After clicking on username input field*
[image]

Comment: Did you check in Edge/Firefox?

Comment: @shhdharmen :) yes, seems like the issue is with the Google Chrome that I used! This configuration worked for Edge!